# Inkscape - Concentric closed paths?

Tags: inkscape, svg, resize, transform, scale

In inkscape I can draw a circle. If I want a bigger circle centred around it like an outline I can just hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys and I'll get concentric circles.
This works because obviously each point on the circumference of a circle is the same distance from the centre point.

Now let's say I have a shape like this :

[image]

Is there a way that I can make a copy of the shape and enlarge it such that it appears concentric to the smaller copy of the shape? As if it were an outline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy task. Copy your existing vector, then use Edit, Paste in Place. Select Path, Dynamic offset and drag the handle to get the desired offset, which will appear "concentric," although that term is inaccurate.

[image: offset check mark]

Comment: Thank you. That's great.

Comment: I realize that Richard used the term concentric in the question, but calling the lines parallel would work.